# playframework scala wrong return type

Tags: scala, playframework

I have the following function:

```
def updateProcessStepTemplate(request: Request[AnyContent]) = Option[Seq[ProcessStepTemplatesModel]] {
    println(request.body.asJson)
    request.body.asJson.map(_.validate[ProcessSteps] match {
      case JsSuccess(processStepTemplates, _) =>

        println("VALIDE SUCCESS -------------------------------")

        println("Valid")

        processStepTemplates.stepsData.map(step => {
          processTemplateDTO.updateProcessStepTemplate(step)
        })

        val test: Seq[ProcessStepTemplatesModel] = processStepTemplates.stepsData
        test
    })
  }
```

And I got this error message:

```
found   : Option[Seq[models.ProcessStepTemplatesModel]]
required: Seq[models.ProcessStepTemplatesModel]
```

What is my failure? Thanks

Comment: I would suspect you need to use getOrElse something like -> processStepTemplates.stepsData.getOrElse(None) and change definition for updateProcessStepTemplate to not use Option[. In any case there is a problem in 2 line from the bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning test field which is type `Seq[ProcessStepTemplatesModel]`. If you want to return it as an option, you need to wrap `test` with `Some()`.

So the last line should be as below:

```
Some(test)
```